# Codeigniter Querying array data against string column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have player_pos column like this:

[image: player_column column]

So want to query data for example if I have array like like 
`player_pos = array('LCV', 'RCV')`
I want to get every user which has value LCV and RCV as player_pos.
How can I do it with Codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($player_pos as $pos){
    $this->db->like('player_pos',$pos);
}
```

I feel so stupid :)